# Appending a header to all PHP files

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I am editing PHP files on my server. I am in the habit of including several comments at the top of each file containing licensing information, my web address, and the version number of the software. I'd like a more convenient way of maintaining this practice without having to manually deal with it when I open and update PHP files on my server. It would be nice if I could also append a timestamp of my recent modification at the bottom of the file too.

I am currently using Dreamweaver 8.0.2.

If Dreamweaver would append this header to the top (taking into account that the file may have a header already in place), that would be acceptable.

If the FTP server would append the file (assuming it is a PHP file) when I download or upload it, that may work too.

I'm unsure what approach to take or what would work for this.

Answer (score 0):

The better option is use "Beyond Compare". It lets you to see file as Explorer and allows you to open multiple files and editing with saving.

I always uses that. So using that, you can open multiple files on server and save them. You don't have to wait for them  that they are saving it on server. Just switch to another file(in new tab)

:)

Answer (score 0):

@David: by whom*

Best solution is to include a header script that checks the last edit date for the time stamp and simply outputs the rest of the information.

All licensing information, web address, and version number of the software should be only changed once for all the files: Thus, echoing from php the comments or simply putting them on a html part would be enough.

As for the timestamp of recent modification, you could use the following script to get the last file update time:

```
$time = filemtime($filename); // You may use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
$convenient_date = date('d-m-Y', $time);
echo "Last modified on {$convenient_date}.";
```

Comment: I don't think you're understanding my question. I'm not wanting to echo anything. I want an easy way to tag each PHP file with a predetermined header of information as I open the files in Dreamweaver or as I save them to the server.

Comment: If you want to dynamically add some text at the beginning of the file, you will probably need a cmd script (I assume you are on Windows if you are using Dreamweaver), using some handmade tags with the [regular expression tool](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/cmd/findstr.html), but then you will need to pass that script every time you save a file with Dreamweaver or submit it with an FTP program. In short: complicated and awkward. It would be best if you centralised the CMS information in a readme, index or bootstrap file.

Comment: You could also set up a PHP program for uploading your scripts to your server, that way you will be able to edit file headers easily with PCRE functions.